# program terminating while shifting string in C

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

Say I have s = " Hello". I want it to convert into s = "Hello".

This is what I have

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
main()
{
    char *s = " Hello";
    char *shift(char *, int);

    shift(s+1,-1);
    printf("%s", s);
}

char *shift (char *str, int units)
{
    if (units < 0)
    {
        for (; *str != '\0'; str++)
            *(str + units) = *str;
        *(str + units) = '\0';
        return str-strlen(str)-units;
    }

}
```

The program is terminating! Not even showing error. Where I am going wrong..

Most importantly, what makes this program to pass the control to OS to terminate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not modify string literals. Also you never check that `str + units` is within the string i.e. it does not go out of the allocated memory of the string(assuming you passed a real string, not a string literal as argument).

Comment: oh! got it.. `char s[] = " hello"` would fix it..